# Installing FIFA 13

Tags: 12.04, wine, games

Is it possible to install FIFA 13 and Origin using Wine.

My graphics card is ATI and its driver is installed in Ubuntu. I wanted to install FIFA 13 using wine. When I tried FIFA 12, it was installed and getting freezed on the game launch.

Comment: After one year I am revisiting the question. Fifa 13 worked and even Fifa 14 Demo worked in wine using the same technique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the WineHQ says that the [FIFA 13 Demo Version](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=14533) works pretty well:

> For launching need to install 'd3dx9_36.dll', 'd3dx9', 'd3dx9_43.dll'
>   only. No one 'dotnetfx' for fifasetup.exe needed.
>
> 1. Go to 'FIFA 13 Demo/instance0' folder on $home
> 2. See file 'replay0.bin', delete and create new with same name and 'chmod 555' properties
> 3. Run the demo

It also says that [Origin](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26175) (assuming this is the "Origin" you speak of) is pretty much garbage:

> **What works**
>
> The application on occasion. Purchasing downloadable content for purchased games.
>
> **What does not**
>
> Attempting to download any game causes: Error:7049.408

So I guess my answer would be yes and no, if you do enough finagling.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use PlayOnLinux available on http://www.playonlinux.com/. PlanOnLinux uses Wine to run Windows software and can install missing dependency like DirectX often needed by the games.

It's seem that only Fifa 11 officially supported, but you can try to choose to install the game manually.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Download the following software:

- Direct X 11
- .Net Framework

Install them and then restart your PC. Run FIFA 13 and enjoy the game.

Answer (score -1):

try installing virtual box
1)install windows inside ubuntu using virtual box
2)install the game inside windows as usual
3)try playing game as usual

post your experiences on the community